# Aggregating on nested fields while using filters on nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

We use Elasticsearch for a library search interface. Our problem is getting the correct aggregation numbers for nested fields when using filters on nested fields.

Our mapping can best be summarized as: A work, having zero or more publications. The mapping, simplified for brewity:

```
{  
   "work":{  
      "properties":{  
         "publication":{  
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{  
               "language":{  
                  "type":"string",
                  "index":"not_analyzed"
               },
               "format":{  
                  "type":"string",
                  "index":"not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         },
         "mainTitle":{  
            "type":"string"
         },
         "partTitle":{  
            "type":"string"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In our search results, we show the works, but we filter on language and format in their publications. Also the aggregations are on language and format. The buckets from the aggregations are used for displaying filtering options to the users in the web UI:
[Picture showing our filter categories and filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1F98.png)

For reference, here is an example query where filters on format "Book" and language "Norwegian" are enabled: [Query](http://pastebin.com/7EY0Z54P)

The search results are correct. Applying format "Book" and language "Norwegian" will only return works that have a publication that is both a book and in Norwegian. Applying the format "Book" and the languages "Norwegian" and "Swedish" will only return works that have a publication that is a book in Norwegian or a book in Swedish.

The problem is that the aggregation numbers (shown as the numbers in the parenthesis after the filters) are not the correct ones. The correct behaviour would be this:

When e.g. applying the filter "Book" and what you get back from the aggregations is "Finnish (3)", then 3 should indicate that there are a total of 3 publications in the work results that are Finnish books.

Instead, what happens is this:

The number shown is simply the number of publications that are in Finnish, but not limited to books and could also be other formats such as DVD or Blu-ray Audio. A user might even get "No results" when enabling the Finnish filter, if there are no Finnish books.

Any hints on how to solve this problem will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what do you want to be shown in parenthesis against `Finnish`?

Comment: @Richa : The number in the parenthesis after Finnish should follow these rules: If just Finnish is selected, then show the number of Finnish publications belonging to the works in the search results. If e.g. "Book" is selected (from a different filter category), then show the number of publications that are Finnish books belonging to the works in the search results. Hope this clarifies things!